# Magento Database Tables restore

Tags: magento-1.7, database, onepage-checkout, magento-1

Something gone bad and all tables related to categories were empty.

```
catalog_category_entity, catalog_category_entity_varchar etc...
```

also

```
catalog_product_entity and catalog_product_entity_index.
```

I restored all of them but now the Onepage does not load... it doesn't display the buttons and the addresses etc.

Are there any tables related to checkout or onepage that i must restore?

Comment: Please have a look in the [great debugging tutorial](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) and report back. If all the tables were empty and you restored them, what is the problem?

Comment: BTW, vote to close in this isn't a good idea. It happens and the day it happens to you, you wish there had been a hint so you DO NOT REPEAT the failure.

Comment: I don't believe there are any tables for the onepage checkout, so the answer to your question is no (correct me if I'm wrong). It would be much easier to help with your problem if you list the set of actions you performed to get to what you are. It is not possible to provide any useful answer with what you have given us.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking "why did this happen?", we can't help :-) - it shouldn't have happened.

Regarding your direct question, just restore everything from your last backup. If that doesn't fix the problem, then update your question.

Comment: Inadequate server resources or poorly setup MySQL parameters. Often because there isn't enough room in the transaction log files to do a proper rollback if the write does not commit.

Answer (score 0):

Check your MySQL configuration and increase the size of the transaction log files to the proper sizing as noted through the manual over on the MySQL website. (64M-128M, check their formula)

This can be the result of a major change you made in the categories not being able to complete and due to a stock baby transaction log (8M), unable to do a rollback on the commit failure.

It's deadly and can eat weeks, months and years of structuring. Also, the result of an inadequate server that doesn't allow enough resources for MySQL to run.

If you look through the MySQL error logs, you probably find it's been warning you for months.